# asp.net core 3 routing actionmethod

Tags: c#

I am using asp.net core 3 and i am having an issue routing to my two actionmethods below.
I would like a way to be able to get hit the action methods.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EventsController : ControllerBase


    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> Details(string id)
    {
        var values = await _Book.Get(id);

        return Ok(values);
    }

    [HttpGet("{filter}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> Filter(string filter)
    {
        var values = await _Book.Get(id);

        return Ok(values);
    }
```

In my startup file i have this routing

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Comment: If 1234 is a book’s id, what does GET /api/events/1234 do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an ambiguous match between `Details` and `Filter` action, because the request matched multiple endpoints, but you could use a custom `route` for each action or just `Filter` action like:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> Details(string id)
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("filter/{filter}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> Filter(string filter)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

And call the methods like :

```
Details ==> https://localhost:44313/api/events/1

Filter ==> https://localhost:44313/api/events/filter/1
```

I hope this help you fix the issue